# Getting typescript Error TS 2604 with package.json type="module"

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

My code is

```
import React from "react";
import Tree from "rc-tree";
export function S() {
    return <Tree>
    </Tree>
}
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "rc-tree": "^5.7.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "target": "es2020",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": ["es2020","dom", "DOM.Iterable"] ,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node16",
        "strict": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "composite":true,
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS"
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules","webpack.config","build"],
    "include": ["**/*.ts*"]
}
```

I am getting a TS Error 2604, when I compile this. If I change type in package.json to "commonjs" or leave it out, the code compiles fine. How can I make it error free when using type="module" - which I need for other reasons.

Comment: When comparing with one of my projects that is using `"type": "module"`; shouldn't `@types/react` exists in devDependencies instead of dependencies?

Comment: Thats correct, but it doesn't change the behavior. I changed the code above in the question. I Also removed some other dependencies irrelevant for the example.